# Iterate over cartesian product of vectors

Tags: r, vector, cartesian-product

I have the following nested loop:

```
for (x in xs) {
    for (y in ys) {
        # Do something with x and y
    }
}
```

Which I’d like to flatten so I thought of building a Cartesian product of the two vectors `xs` and `ys` and iterating over the result. In Python, this would be trivial:

```python
for xy in product(xs, ys):
    # x, y = xy[0], xy[1]
```

But in R, the simplest equivalent I’ve found looks daunting:

```
xys <- expand.grid(xs, ys)
for (i in 1 : nrow(xys)) {
    xy <- as.vector(xys[i, ])
    # x <- xy[1], y <- xy[2]
}
```

Surely there must be a better way, no? (To clarify, I don’t want to iterate over an *index* … I think there must be a way to directly iterate over the tuples in the product.)

Comment: just a note that the python example can be made even more trivial:
`for x, y in product(xs, ys):`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function to apply a function to each row of your data frame. Just replace `"your function"` with your actual function.

```
# example data
xs <- rnorm(10)
ys <- rnorm(10)    

apply(expand.grid(xs, ys), 1, FUN = function(x) {"your function"})
```

This is a very basic example. Here, the sum of both values in a row is calculated:

```
apply(expand.grid(xs, ys), 1, FUN = function(x) {x[1] + x[2]})
```

---

Here is a variant that uses named arguments (`xs`, `ys`) instead of indices (`x[1]`, `x[2]`):

```
myfun <- function(xs, ys) xs + ys
arguments <- expand.grid(xs = rnorm(10), ys = rnorm(10))
apply(arguments, 1, function(x)do.call(myfun, as.list(x)))
```

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I undeleted my answer. There was nothing wrong with it. I wasn't sure whether it was exactly the solution you looked for. @flodel is right about the problems using `apply` with mixed input types. In this case, you could use `as.numeric` to transform a string into a numeric value. But there is no problem as long as you use numeric vectors only.

Answer (score 11):

R has a different paradigm than Python, so don't expect it to have generators or tuples -- we have vectors and indices for that.

This way, to map a function on a Cartesian product simply call

```
outer(xs,ys,function(x,y) ...)
```

and undim the result if you wish.

EDIT: In case `xs` or `ys` are something more complex than base vectors, one option is to use indices, i.e.

```
outer(seq(a=xs),seq(a=ys),function(xi,yi) ... xs[[xi]]/ys[xi,]/etc. ...)
```

or map a function on a bit hand-crafted product using `mapply`

```
mapply(function(x,y) ...,xs,rep(ys,each=length(xs)))
```

Comment: I’m not concerned with different paradigms. I *am* concerned about the pervasiveness of index variables in my code. As far as I understand R, most/all of them should be unnecessary. Your example code *looks* like what I’ve searched by it behaves in the wrong way: `outer(1:2, 3:4, function(x, y) { print(sprintf('%d,%d', x, y)) }` – this prints an array *and* a matrix with the results – so I don’t know how to rewrite my loop to work here … (I don’t know what you mean by “undim”, maybe this would explain it.)

Comment: Uuh, the previous comment is stupid. The matrix is just the return value of `outer`. Nevertheless, I’m still not sure how to adapt this to work as a replacement of my nested loop, since `x` and `y` are vectors, not scalars. Unfortunately, I really do need scalars.

Comment: Cheers. This was indeed helpful but I think Sven has posted an even simpler / more directly applicable answer below … and deleted it. Is there anything wrong with his answer which I’m too inexperienced to see? It seems to work perfectly for my problem.

Comment: Nah, it was ok; only that `expand.grid` won't work on any more complex structures than `outer`... It is only superior in case of more dimensions.

Comment: Oh my, came back to this, and `outer` sent me on a merry goose chase for 1/2 hour while I tried to figure out why my callback function is only called *once* rather than for each combination. Turns out, `outer` does that, and expects the callback to be vectorised. Of course one look into the documentation would have saved me. But such is the human condition …