# Writing a for loop with two variables in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterate over cartesian product of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338092/iterate-over-cartesian-product-of-vectors)

Is there a way to have two different variables i and j in the same for loop in R?

In the for loop I have two commands one referring to variable i ranging from 1 to 80 and one for j ranging from 1 to 20.

Is there a way to do this?

this is what I would like to do:

```
For i in 1:length(matrix$firstrow)

a<-subset(matrix1, matrix[,1]=i)

For j in 1:length(matrix2$secondrow)
b<-matrix2[j,2]
```

So I have two matrices and to variables i and j

Comment: It is likely that you can achieve your goal better without a `for` loop.

Comment: Roland I've edited the question to make it clear what I'm trying to do. thanks for your help

Comment: what is the relation between the two matrix? are the results a and b related(e.g. is b taken from the subset)???

Comment: @A.R. unfortunately no. these are two separate, unrelated matrices

Comment: As these are completely independent operations, why would you want to put them into the same loop in the first place?

Comment: If you made a small reproducible example and clear indication of what you're trying to achieve, maybe we can help.